# What does the /= operator mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

What does the operator `/=` (slash equals) mean in Python?

I know `|=` is a set operator. I have not seen `/=` previously though.

Comment: This operator can be useful when dealing with paths:

Comment: @FoxyFox How could it be used in paths?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's an assignment operator shorthand for `/` and `=`.

Example:

```
x = 12
```

```
x /= 3
# equivalent to
x = x / 3
```

If you use `help('/=')`, you can get the full amount of symbols supported by this style of syntax (including but not limited to `+=`, `-=`, and `*=`), which I would strongly encourage.

Answer (score 3):

It's an augmented assignment operator for floating point division. It's equivalent to

```
x = x / 3
```

Per Makota's answer above, the following is provided by python 3, including the target types and operators, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements for more info:

augmented_assignment_stmt ::= augtarget augop (expression_list | yield_expression)

augtarget                 ::= identifier | attributeref | subscription | slicing

augop                     ::= "+=" | "-=" | "*=" | "@=" | "/=" | "//=" | "%=" | "**="
             | ">>=" | "<<=" | "&=" | "^=" | "|="